# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).Only in server I am getting

Tags: jquery

Below is my code, which handler is called. If I try to call it is throwing error.

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
    url: '../HttpHandler/AjaxFileUploader.ashx', //handler
    secureuri: false,
    fileElementId: id,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { name: 'logan', id: 'id' },
    responseType: 'json',
    success: function (data, status) {
        if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
            if (data.error != '') {
                alert(id)
                alert(data.error);
            } else {
                alert("File Uploaded Successfully");
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (data, status, e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you include jQuery in your code ?

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look at the server logfiles for exceptions.

Comment: If you get an error, the jQuery AJAX call is probably fine, maybe it's the server response, headers, or something related what is causing the error.

Comment: I have included jquery. In local it is working fine. But if i upload in the server it is causing the error.